# Is there a cantor pairing function for spirals?

Tags: number-theory

Similarly to how cantor pairing function works by pairing two numbers >=0 to 1 unique number >=0, and where the ordering goes zig zag like dovetailing, is there a way to map numbers including negative ones to unique numbers but for a spiral pattern?

In this image, the center is centered on (0,0). Given a square of odd length, i.e. 1, 3, 5, 7..., does there exist a function that can map the coordinates to the ones indicated in red font? Like `(0,0) -> 0`, `(1, -2)->11`?

Does anyone know?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Are you asking for an explicit function that describes the mapping?

Comment: I would prefer an explicit formula if it exists.

Answer (score 2):

Given two integers $x$ and $y,$ here's a formula for the position $f(x,y)$ of the pair $(x,y)$ in the spiral sequence.

First let $s$ be whichever of $x$ and $y$ has greater absolute value.  (If $x$ and $y$ have the same absolute value, just set $s=x.$)  Then

$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
4s^2-x+y, &\text{if }s \ge 0,\\
4s^2+(-1)^{\delta_{s,x}}(2s+x+y), &\text{if }s < 0.
\end{cases}$$

Here $\delta_{s,x}$ is the Kronecker delta, which is $1$ if $s=x,$ and $0$ otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Of course there is such a function. You've just "defined" it by your picture!
The fact that we might not know how to write it as a formula can by no means endanger the pure existence of the mapping.

Comment: The OP's question seems to be "Is this picture valid?"  Your answer asserts that it is, but doesn't really address the question of why...  As such, I don't think that your answer really addresses the question.